# VMWare vSphere - Edit NFS datastore settings?

Tags: vmware-esx, nfs

I'm rebuilding one of my NFS storage units for a VMWare vSphere setup. As a result, the NFS exports' (datastore) paths defined on the ESX hosts are going to change from: `/vol1/xxx` to `/volumes/vol1/xxx`. I also may move some from VMDK files from `/vol1/xxx` to `/volumes/vol2/xxx`. Is there a quick way via the ESX command line or otherwise to redefine the mount points or paths of existing datastores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here was to remove the datastores and recreate them. There were no shortcuts. This was at a time where I was using ESX (versus ESXi), so I used the service console to remap the mounts.